# This script in not compatible with jquery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script works fine when I include jquery 1.8.3 but it won't work with jquery 3.2.1 what should I change? [here](https://docs.sonhlab.com/protect-javascript-from-copying/) the link where it comes from

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo of Protecting Javascript Code From Copying</title>

<!-- jQuery Library 1.8.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.183.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'js/js.php',
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      if(data){
        $('body').append(data);
      }
    }
  }); 
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
  Demo of Protecting Javascript Code From Copying.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens? Did you look in the console / debugger for errors?

Comment: `won't work` ... why do you say it wont?

Comment: Did you look at the [api reference](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)? The load event was removed in 3.x series, so your code is trying to use the ajax function [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) instead of the load event

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [upgrade guide to jQuery 3.0](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/). It has a bunch of breaking changes..

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).on("load",function() {` instead of `$(window).load(function() {`

The [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method, as a way to bind the `load` event, was deprecated since jQuery 1.8. and removed in 3.0

> Removed deprecated event aliases
>   .load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more. Use .on() to register listeners.

**Reference:** [Release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) *(Keyword search for "load" -> 3rd result.)*

The actual, still valid [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, is a shorhand to the `.ajax()` method.

In this second link for `.load()` *(two different links! look closely!)*, you can read:

> Note: Prior to jQuery 3.0, the event handling suite also had a method named .load(). Older versions of jQuery determined which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it.

As [Andre Figueiredo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986862/andre-figueiredo) mentioned in comments, have a close look to [**jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/). Many things changed between 1.8.3 and 3.2.1. The firsts I have in mind, because frequently asked, are [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).